# Python Type Hinting - hint a filtered list understand the type

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have two classes instances in a list:

```py
from typing import List, Union

class A:
  my_type: str = 'A'
class B:
  my_type: str = 'B'

my_list: List[Union[A, B]] = [A(),A(),B(),B()]
As: List[A] = [a for a in my_list if a.my_type == 'A']

def function_that_gets_only_array_of_As(arr: List[A]):
    print(arr)

function_that_gets_only_array_of_As(As) # this yields a type hint error
```

how would I hint that As is of type List[A] ?

Comment: `As: List[A] = ...`…?

Comment: first you have to import List from typing module, (`from typing import List`), then just put `As: List[A]`

Comment: That wouldn't work, since my_list is of A() A(), B(), B()...I'll rephrase

Comment: @Mr.Nun. but, you are filtering to get only the A ones.
You can type a list containing both A and B by using `List[Union[A, B]]`
But in this case, `List[A]` is fine.

PD: Maybe to get only the A ones it would be better to use `isinstance` like `As = [a for entity in my_list if isinstance(a, A)]`

Comment: So, why doesn't `As: List[A] = [...]` work…?

Comment: @Mr.Nun. `Union` should do the job now

Comment: try running it with pyright, you'll get an error

Comment: Your code does not raise an error / warning on my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA)

Comment: Both mypy and pyright seem to be complaining about this, true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [type assertion/cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) to override the inferred type:

```
from typing import cast

As = cast(List[A], [...])
```

It's basically up to you there to ensure that your types are what you declare them to be.